# How to use url id in where clause dynamically

Tags: php

how to use url id of one page for other page in where clause
like 
i have send http://localhost/Eshopper/products.php?id=1
where the id is for product like in my table i have tbl_products
 in that

product_id ,produc_name , brand_id
where the brand is select form menu linke i have menu for samsung when we click on that it will shown all samsung mobile 
i have use where query for getting data i was able to get the data by passing manual id like

SELECT * FROM `tbl_products` WHERE brand_id=1
but i want to get this  brand id=1 from url that i passed through
 http://localhost/Eshopper/products.php?id=1
so this id 1 automacticlly added to the where condtion so to do this

Comment: Can you kindly [edit] your question and make it readable?

Comment: $_GET['id'] will hold the id value from the url.

Comment: After your query, add this line.

`if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $query .= " WHERE product_id = '" . (int) $_GET['id'] . "'";
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

For example, you url is `id=1`:

So,

```
<?php

/** ID is not set or it is not a integer. **/
if (!isset($_GET['id']) || !filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))
    exit('Invalid ID.');

/** Remove other characters. **/
$iD = intval($_GET['id']);

?>
```

We first check if the `id` is set and if it is an actual number.

Then we sanitize the input to remove everything that isn't numeric.

**Reading Material**

[`isset`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjA2rjjz5fKAhVEuhQKHYZRAygQFggjMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.isset.php&usg=AFQjCNEilnOC2VNydDdQDAXjnJjWAYf6Mg&bvm=bv.110151844,d.d24)

[`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

[`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the id on multiple pages by saving it in a session as follows.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}

// Set $_GET id to $_SESSION id
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id'];
}

// Set default value
if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = 1;
}


// Now you can use $_SESSION['id'] instead of $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: i was able to get id by url i just unable to  got that id into where condition

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get id by url I just unable to get that id into where condition like

```
$url = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
query = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_products` WHERE brand_id= '$url'";

echo $query;
```

so I get id=1 when I echo but when put this `$query` in where it was not get data

When I use static id I get data

like

```
$query = "select * from tbl_products where brand_id=1";
```

then I get list like one, two, three

But when I use

```
$query = "select * from tbl_products where brand_id='$url'";
```

I don't get any data so what is issue with this query